# How to append the javascript Mutation Observer for dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I have a scenario, where the DOM element may be or may not be loads on page load with style display block or none.

1. If the dom element loads on page on page load with display block, then I should not do anything, if it loads on page load with style display none, then I have to append the observer to that particular element, once that element changes to display block then I need to fire a method.
2. Currently the above scenario works fine if the dom element loads on page load with display none/block.
3. But in the scenario, where the dom element doesn't load on page load, I need to write a watch method, where it will check whether the element is loaded or not and I don't have any hold who and when the element will get append. Once the element is available on page, I need to follow the above point 1 and 2.

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="test"> 1234567890 </div>
```

JS:

```
var o_sel;
var o_obj ='';
o_obj = $("*:contains('123')*:contains('4567')");
if(o_obj.length != 0){
    if(o_obj.last()[0].innerHTML.indexOf('890') >= 0){
        for(var i=o_obj.length-1; i>=0; --i){
            if($(o_obj[i]).is(':hidden') == true){
                if($(o_obj[i]).css('display') == 'none'){
                    o_sel=o_obj[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(o_sel){
            var o_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                    alert('found');                                                 
                });    
            });
            var config = {attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['style']};
            o_observer.observe(o_sel,config);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally you should know when you insert elements, and when you change attributes, so it's only in very special cases that intervals, mutation observers etc. should be used.

Comment: @adeneo, Yes  agree, but the problem is I need to check the attribute change for the element which I dont know when it will load on the page.

Comment: Who or what change the attribute?

Comment: @LGSon: Changed the question description with proper requirement.

Comment: Is it not your code that might or might not load the element?

Comment: Uhm, so simply add another MutationObserver and check each  of addedNodes for its textContent.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you please help with some sample code